# Unit tests are always aborted

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I am using VS-2013, windows 8.1 and trying to write some unit tests for my login page using NUnit. All the time it shows me the message 'Aborted'.

[image]

Secondly, I wrote a cleanup method but it never gets executed.
As I am new to it, I have no idea how to debug this code. I am using resharper and I just do a right click on `Can_Go_To_LoginPage` method and click the option `Run Unit Tests`. I applied break points as well but it never stops at a break point.

Answer (score 13):

Visual studio 2019 - Mine was missing NET Core SDK's

1. Click on View > Output
2. Change "Show output from " to "Test"

it should tell you what exactly SDKs you are missing

Answer (score 5):

Ok I just figured out how to debug it. I just right clicked on the last aborted method i.e. `Can_Go_To_LoginPage` and there was an option to debug this unit test. It executed the code line by line and there was a recursive call in another class which was throwing `StackOverflowException`. I just fixed that out and the problem gone away :)

Comment: It was a `StackOverflowException` for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem, my tests abruptly stopped, however I saw nothing in the output as to the issue.  I had to run the tests from the command line to see what was the underlying problem.  In my case some of my references were not able to be located, but I was not seeing this error in my output.

Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt and run:

```
MSTest /testcontainer:path\to\your\test.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Right click And "Debug" as opposed to simply "Run".

It should break at the point at which the Test fails and provide an error message.